# How to read and change BAM files from a Python script?

Tags: python

I'm planning on using a Python script to change different BAM ([Binary Alignment Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Alignment_Map)) file headers. Right now I am just testing the output of one bam file but every time I want to check my output, the `stdout` is not human readable. How can I see the output of my script? Should I use `samtools view bam.file` on my script? This is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess


if __name__=='__main__':
    for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if file == "SRR4209928.bam":
            with open("SRR4209928.bam", "r") as input:
                content = input.readlines()
                for line in content:
                    print(line)
```

Comment: If you already know the name of the file you want, you don't need a loop.

Comment: `BAM` is a binary version of [`SAM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAM_(file_format)) so you just can't `open()` and `readlines()` from it. You will need something that knows how to deal with that kind of file.

Comment: Take a look at [`pysam`](https://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html). I guess it will make your life easier when dealing with those `.bam` files.

Comment: @chepner you are right, but I just wanted to deal with one file first. I'll edit it.

Comment: Great! Thank you, @ accdias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `BAM` is a binary type of `SAM`, you will need to write something that knows how to deal with the compressed data before you can extract something meaningful from it. Unfortunately, you can't just `open()` and `readlines()` from that type of file.

If you are going to write a module by yourself, you will need to read [Sequence Alignment/Map Format Specification](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMv1.pdf).

Fortunately someone already did that and created a Python module: You can go ahead and check [`pysam`](https://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pysam-an-interface-for-reading-and-writing-sam-files) out. It will surely make your life easier.

I hope it helps.